# How can I check if an input contains space characters only. I.e. one or more spaces only and no other characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect on focusout if an input field contains only spaces. ie 1 or more spaces only and not any other characters?

At the moment it only detects if it contains 1 space only

```
$("#myInput").on("focusout",function(){
    if($(this).val() ==" "){ 
        //do work
    }
});
```

Comment: As an aside: beware to [define spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Spaces_in_Unicode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
if (/^\s+$/.test($(this).val())) { ...
```

Comment: I really wish the SO editor had parenthesis highlighting. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Trim and compare length and check if length is zero.

```
$("#myInput").on("focusout",function(){
    if($(this).val().length && $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0){ 
        alert("string contains one or more spaces")
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't that also be true if the string is empty?

Comment: its nice but it also catches the empty string

Comment: Check my updated answer, now it will check if string is not empty string already.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the trim option.

Trim the input value then check if it is empty.

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');};

    String.prototype.ltrim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+/,'');};

    String.prototype.rtrim=function(){return this.replace(/\s+$/,'');};

    String.prototype.fulltrim=function(){return this.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (yourstring.match(/^\S+([\s\xA0]|&nbsp;)+/, '')){
```